# Import whitespace value to LDAP using LDIF

Tags: ldap, ldif

LDAP doesn't allow empty field values. Once I needed to use empty field, I inserted single space instead (using ruby code). Now I've exported the data to LDIF, and in LDIF whitespace doesn't matter, and so in LDIF my value of a single space is not preserved.

Now I've exported `data.ldif` from that LDAP instance, and wish to import it to another LDAP instance. However, LDAP complains about empty fields, since in LDIF whitespace doesn't matter, and my single space values are not preserved in any special way.

Is there a way to preserve my single space values in LDIF? (should I put quotes around them or something like that?)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! One can encode space in base64:

Find-replace:

```
middleName:␣␣
```

to

```
middleName:: IA==
```

Double column means the following is encoded in base64. `IA==` is a single utf-8 space, encoded in base64.